# Unable to generate exe installer for netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created Java SE project in Apache Netbeans IDE 10.0

When I select "package as EXE installer" I get the following error:

```
C:\repos\6551_salamander\SalamanderJava\nbproject\build-native.xml:519: typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compile with a dependency that is not available `com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar`. Make sure you have the correct dependencies added for your project and then try again.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure of which dependencies I should add and how I should add them.

Comment: Make sure that in Netbeans you have added the JavaFX libraries to your project, otherwise, I suspect that JavaFX is not correctly setup in NetBeans. You can always try adding the JavaFX jar as an external library by downloading it from the official site: https://openjfx.io/