# Netbeans 11.1 Exe installer build failed

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, installation, inno-setup

First of all, this is not a duplicate of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560242/unable-to-generate-exe-installer-for-netbeans-project). There are no solutions there as such. I am using Netbeans 11.1 and the application is using JDK 12 (**Note**: running it using Java 13 does not change anything). I have imported all the JavaFX libraries (see screenshot below). I am able to build the .jar file. I also have my Inno Set Up 6 integrated with Netbeans with native packaging enabled. However, when I try to package as "Exe installer" I run into the following error:

if anyone has any fix for this, please let me know. I am able to build a dmg installer but not exe, which kinda sucks!

```
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.0
Result: 1
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build
clean:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build\classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
Note: C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\src\mixregui\mixregGUI.java uses or overrides a 
deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
Copying 41 files to C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\dist
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Copying 20 files to C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\dist\lib
Copied 4 empty directories to 4 empty directories under C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\dist\lib
C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\MixWildGUI\nbproject\build-native.xml:519: typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

[image]

Comment: To me, the question is has Inno been updated to work with Java 9+?

Comment: It seems netbeans 11 can't export to exe installer yet with javaFX and JDK 13. I reverted back to JDK 8 and Netbeans 8.2 and it worked fine.

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: Netbeans 11 still does not have support to build windows build. The Inno seems not compatible. I moved back to Netbeans 8 (hate it)